# Cohomology of sheaf of differentials on singular Fano variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

It is known that if $X$ is a smooth Fano Manifold of Picard number one, then $H^0(X, \Omega_X^1) = 0$ and $H^1(X, \Omega_X^1) \simeq \mathbb{C}$.

Question: Are the same results hold true if $X$ is a projective Fano variety (not smooth but singular locus has co-dimension at least 3) ?

Comment: I don't think what you are claiming is true. There are Fano threefolds (smooth) with larger than $1$, $h^{1,1}$. Look at table 1 [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0550321317302262)

Comment: Sorry, I missed the hypothesis of Picard number one.